# Image parsing, formatting, rendering in REACT

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux, html-parsing

I'm working with DomParser to import a document in 'text/html' format into REACT to work with it, so far all the texts and tables have been formatted well using this method, however I cannot get the images to show up, given that when I inspect the image element it's not displaying for the following reasons:

My question would be, how would I make img.src = img.data-original ? Is there a quick way to get data-original into src?

What I've tried is making: img.src = img.dataOriginal; which is undefined. See code below.

```
function format(file) {
  if(file === null) return; 

  const document = new DomParser().parseFromString(file, 'text/html'); 

  // text table format 
  document.querySelectorAll('table').forEach((table) => {
    table.className = 'table'; 
  }); 

  // img 
  document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach((img) => {
     img.className = 'img'; 
     img.src = img.dataOriginal; // this is undefined - is there a way to get data-original into src?

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do this

```
function format(file) {
  if(file === null) return; 

  const document = new DomParser().parseFromString(file, 'text/html'); 

  // text table format 
  document.querySelectorAll('table').forEach((table) => {
    table.className = 'table'; 
  }); 

  // img 
  document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach((img) => {
     img.className = 'img'; 
     img.src = img.getAttribute('data-original');
     // or img.src = img.dataset.original;
});
```

The DOMParser returns The DOM for you so you can do with it as you do with the regular DOM (document object)

Comment: @ToniHe What do you mean by DataOriginal then

Comment: @ToniHe is dataOriginal a custom attribute

Comment: dataOriginal is from the img tag which I inspected: 

<img class="img" src="" alt="" data-original="actualfileIneed.jpg"> 

It's automatically rendered, so each one has an empty src="", but a data-original that has the path to the file that's why I was wondering how I would be able to pull data-original into src.

Comment: @ToniHe ok sorry now i understand your question, i edited my answer so that it works